# Terraform Azurerm backend writing ok but not reading

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to set up a simple Terraform backend on Azure. I am able to write but it seems reading does not really work. For example, I tried to add an `azurerm_resource_group` called `test_a`, then `terraform init` and `terraform apply` and it was stored correctly on a bucket on Azure.

I modified my code and changed the name of my resource to call it `test_b` then `terraform init` and `terraform apply` and terraform destroyed my `test_a` and added my `test_b` resource. "`Apply complete! Resources: 1 added, 0 changed, 1 destroyed.`". What can be the issue? I can see that whenever I am running my `terraform init` command, it's still generating a `.terraform` folder with a `terraform.tfstate` inside.

**main.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~>2.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "~>1.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test_a" {
  name     = "testing-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}
```

**backend_config.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_version = ">= 0.12.6"
  
  backend "azurerm" {
    subscription_id      = "a095c3dd-xxx"
    resource_group_name  = "terraform"
    storage_account_name = "terraform963"
    container_name       = "tfstate"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
  }
}
```

**terraform.tfstate (stored in Azure)**

```
{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "0.14.3",
  "serial": 4,
  "lineage": "1fcb0f9a-7c26-xxx",
  "outputs": {},
  "resources": [
    {
      "mode": "managed",
      "type": "azurerm_resource_group",
      "name": "test_b",
      "provider": "provider[\"registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm\"]",
      "instances": [
        {
          "schema_version": 0,
          "attributes": {
            "id": "/subscriptions/a095c3dd-xxx/resourceGroups/testing-resources",
            "location": "westeurope",
            "name": "testing-resources",
            "tags": null,
            "timeouts": null
          },
          "sensitive_attributes": [],
          "private": "eyJlMmJmYjczxxx="
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terraform uses this state to create plans and make changes to your infrastructure. Prior to any operation, Terraform does a refresh to update the state with the real infrastructure. In this case, you only change the resource name and keep the existing resource_group name. Terraform will require to [import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/import/index.html) the existing infrastructure into the state.

> Warning: **Terraform expects that each remote object it is managing will
> be bound to only one resource address**, which is normally guaranteed by
> Terraform itself having created all objects. If you import existing
> objects into Terraform, be careful to import each remote object to
> only one Terraform resource address.

You will import the state with the command `terraform import azurerm_resource_group.test_b <existingResourceGroupID>`. Once you have imported the existing infrastructure, terraform will try to add the resource `azurerm_resource_group.test_b` according to the latest state.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Id there any way to just import the `tfstate.tf` file before to write on it? I mean your solution works but if I do have 100 ressources and I don't know their names

Comment: `"The current implementation of Terraform import can only import resources into the state. It does not generate configuration. Because of this, prior to running terraform import it is necessary to write manually a resource configuration block for the resource, to which the imported object will be mapped."` If you have 100 resources, you have to import each resource one by one because the command currently can only import one resource at a time.

Comment: You may take a look at this tool [terraformer](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer) which may do the trick to help you generates tf/json and tfstate files based on existing infrastructure. More info refer [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/Terraform/comments/f80ngl/terraform_import_a_set_of_resources/)

Comment: Thanks, everything is ok now ;D